# How to convert numbers to dates in SSRS Report Builder

Tags: reporting-services, reportbuilder

I am writing a report in SSRS Report Builder. The date field I am pulling in from my Data Set gives me a string of numbers (ie: 43706). This number is pulling from Excel. Excel stores dates as numbers. It assumes a starting date of 1/1/1900 and counts every day that has happened since then. So 8/29/2019 is 43,706 days after 1/1/1900. This would convert to 8/29/2019 in excel, but I can not figure out how to convert it in SSRS. I tried Cdate and FormatDateTime with no success. Is there another solution?

Comment: How in the world does 43706 convert to 8/29/2019?  There is no logical connection between that number and date.  Please explain how you expect that number to convert into that date.

Comment: Can you not define the field as date in your DS? If you are pulling this data from a DB then you can insure the correct datatype in your query.

Comment: Steve - Excel stores dates as numbers. It assumes a starting date of 1/1/1900 and counts every day that has happened since then. So 8/29/2019 is 43,706 days after 1/1/1900. And briskovich I apologize, but I am very new to SSRS. My datasource is an already created SQL server. Is it still possible to redefine the field? Would I do that in the dataset?

Comment: Ahhh so it's days.  I'll put together an answer based on that comment.  Meanwhile, you should probably [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57207628/edit) those details into your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the additional information, you should be able to use the `DateAdd` function to convert the number into the specified date.  `DateAdd` requires 3 parameters - the date part to add, a number of that date part, and the date to add the number of date parts to.  For example, your scenario would require an expression like the following.

```
=DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, 43706, CDate("1/1/1900"))
```

Assuming the date is coming from some field, however, you'll simply replace the number with whatever the field is called such as `Fields!DateConversion.Value`.

Additionally, with a quick test, there may be some issue with leap years or something similar?  If you'd like to match exactly what Excel does, you might need to subtract 2 from the field.

```
=DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, (Fields!DateConversion.Value - 2), CDate("1/1/1900"))
```